# Ubuntu in VMware 12 freeze as soon as the USB deveice connection

Tags: 16.04, usb, freeze

**Environment:**

> Vmware Workstaion 12 pro
>
> Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (in the Vmware)
>
> ThinkPad T480

**Backgrounds:**

I meet a strange problem about ubuntu and USB connection. Two days ago I wanted to do some tests on a USB 3.0 camera. I could connect it successfully first and use its SDK to get the information (some configrutions and settings). I think that in that time everything was OK. But when I tried to run another SDK program it was broken and Ubuntu was frozen. After that time, when I tried to connect the camera, Ubuntu was sure to freeze. Even the USB deveices are the camera inside the laptop and a external USB flash, Ubuntu is also frozen.

**What I have done:**

I had no choice but to reinstall the Vmware and Ubuntu in it. But the problem is also there. I can't understand the reason. All the USB deveices in win10 can work well.

So is there anyone who can say something? Thank you!

**EDIT 1:**

I am not familiar with the specific principle about the keyboard and mouse function bewteen Ubuntu in VWmare and WIN 10. I try to re-connect the mouse and keyboard and Ubuntu is right. I am not sure whether it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I make it! I find the reason why Ubuntu in VMware will be freeze when I connect the USB deveices. I search the Vmware community and see that https://communities.vmware.com/thread/612551?q=freeze%20USB%20connection

Many in it said that it seemed to be with Win 10 1903 version. And I found that VMware 15.1 version has solved the compatibility issues. So I update the VMware and make it!

Oh dear!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in VMWare Workstation 15 Player. Here when user connect USB it asks to user for permission to connect VMware or host system. So no issue observed here unlike older VMware Workstations.